# single cryptic crossword clue... sofa besmirched with urine? Nasty [9]

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, crossword-clues

single cryptic crossword clue.

> Sofa besmirched with urine? Nasty [9]

This was a clue in a recent cryptic puzzle I saw in a newspaper. I reproduce it here as I thought it might be of interest.

Comment: Late to the game, missed this.  But is this valid?  I'd accept "Besmirched  sofa with urine"  but I really  don't like the separating of the fodder by the indicator.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore - in fact I disagree here - e.g. ball kicked by foot vs kicked ball with foot - the first phrase means the ball was kicked with a foot and the second implies I kicked the ball with my foot. In this context I think the first sentence in the 'passive voice' is more appropriate because it makes the focus on the foot and the ball

Comment: The surface reading is irrelevant..  The wordplay phrase is "Sofa Besmirched with Urine".  Clearly Besmirched is the anagram indicator.  So as written, this means Anagram(SOFA) + URINE (or  synonym).   Besmirched sofa with urine would mean Anagram(SOFA + URINE)  which is how the clue is solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> NEFARIOUS

because

> it's an anagram of SOFA+URINE and means nasty.

Comment: Yes you have it, but, of course, you knew that already :-) plus one and green check markers on the way...